# What's similar to "over-engineered" but used in context of communication, like saying something overly complicated for the sake of "professionalism"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Title says it all:

What's a word or phrase similar to "over-engineered" but used in the context of communication, like saying something overly complicated for the sake of "professionalism"?

Comment: Formal: *Circumlocution*. Informal: ***Waffle***.

Comment: CYA legalese, like the kind in TV spots that say not to take the drug being pitched if you're allergic to the drug being pitched.

Comment: In your question, is "communication" related to technology for transmission of information (e.g. phone, wi-fi, ...) or the act of exchanging with people (press, conversation, speech, ...) ?

Comment: This is especially while giving a talk or a speech more than in writing. There is still meaning communicated but in a way that is not considered to be in layman's terms or something informal or easy to understand

Comment: You can look into `prolix`. It means `(of writing, a speech, etc.) using too many words and therefore boring` which is not 100% fit to your purpose but has a nice ring to it. The noun form - `prolixity`-  is lot more common in usage. Maybe you can use as a phrase- `official prolixity`  . Also , at times mere  `officialese` does the work.

Comment: Only tangentially related, but I just like the word: "sesquipedalian" can be defined as "a word like 'sesquipedalian'" or as "someone who uses words like 'sesquipedalian'".

Comment: Thank you for all your suggestions ... Learnt a lot more words than I asked for, but think i found an answer that's close enough. Thank you all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you said you wanted something "similar to over-engineered," I latched onto the "over" prefix and "**overwrought**" popped into my mind.  Though depending on your specific context that may be a bit too strong; [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/135395)'s sense 2 for it has:

> 2. Excessively elaborate; over-laboured. Also (occasionally) figurative.

I've certainly heard it occasionally used in the "figurative" way---applied to discourse---which would be the way it applies to your situation, if it does, I'd guess.

Comment: Yep! The secondary meaning sounds about right! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Consider these :

> [Pretentious](https://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=pretentious) [speech] :
>
> > Making claim to or creating an appearance of (often undeserved) importance or distinction
> > Intended to attract notice and impress others

> [grandiloquence](https://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=grandiloquence) :
>
> > High-flown style; excessive use of verbal ornamentation

> [grandiose](https://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=grandiose) :
>
> > Impressive because of unnecessary largeness or grandeur; used to show disapproval

Those 3 are formal , this is informal :

> [Claptrap](https://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=claptrap)
>
> > Pompous or pretentious talk or writing

My Example Usage :

> The Politician gave a very Pretentious/grandiose/grandiloquent Speech , Devoid of much meaning.
> It was full of Claptrap , though it was catering to his Voter Base.

Answer (score 0):

The word **circumlocutory** would be a good fit, though of course this word is rather uncommon. This is derived from "circumlocution," defined [by TFD as](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/circumlocutory) "the use of unnecessarily wordy language, especially in being vague or evasive."

Answer (score 0):

I'd put forward 'over-thought' - the OP seems to suggest that more than enough information was supplied for good compliance, but continued to 'over-egg' that particular pudding.
In my line of work I have to explain things in tedious detail because my target audience is talented at extracting tangential meaning from the most innocuous looking text - their being prone to over-thinking every scintilla.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).